# making a class Name_class and storing two data types in a single vector

Tags: c++

*i don't know* the meaning of 
**Name_value(std::string n, int v)
        :name(n), value(v) { }**
how do these two lines work?

```
#include "std_library_facilities.h"

void error(std::string b)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(b);
}

class Name_value
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int value;
    Name_value(std::string n, int v)
        :name(n), value(v) { }
};


int main()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no vectors involved here; what you see is the declaration of a class `Name_value` and its [constructor](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_constructors.asp) `Name_value::Name_value(std::string, int)`.

Constructors are a really basic thing that you're going to have to understand before you do anything in C++.

A constructor is a special class member that sets up a new object of that class type. In this case, the constructor 's definition (declared inline in the class definition)

```
Name_value(std::string n, int v):
       name(n), value(v) { }
```

sets any new `Name_value` object's `name` member to the value of `n` and it's `value` member to `v`

So, if your `main` contains something like this

```
int main()
{
 Name_value n ("foo", 8);
}
```

Then `n.name` would be set to a `std::string` containing "foo" and `n.value` would be set to `8`.

Answer (score 0):

`Name_value(std::string n, int v)` is a constructor for `Name_value` taking two arguments (`n` and `v`).

`: name(n), value(v)` is the constructors *initialization list* where you initialize class member variables. In this case, the member `name` is initialized from `n` and `value` is initialized from `v`.

The `{ }` bit is the body of the constructor - which is empty because nothing except initialization (which has already been done) needs to be done for this constructor.